# Trying to set cookie, but it says undefined. What do i do?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

So here is my code

```
<script>
function ls() {
var text = document.getElementById("name").value;
document.cookie = "username=" + text + ";";
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = text;

}
</script>
<p id="name"><p>
<input type="text" id = "textbox"> <br/>
<input type="Submit" value = " Submit " onClick = "ls()">
```

And when i run it and enter a value into the text box the press submit it creates the cookie but with a "undefined" as the value. Also the "name" text is set to "undefined"

Anyone know what im doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You confused your id's. Use textbox instead of name.

```
var text = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
```